# MAMP localhost filed leading to nothing

Tags: wordpress

I've been running Wordpress locally and after updating to Catalina, I've run into a lot of problems accessing.
When I enter http://localhost:8888/ I get an index of only Wordpress, click onto the Wordpress and receive :

> Not Found
>   The requested URL was not found on this server.

If I go into http://127.0.0.1:8888/wordpress/, I receive an index of the seperate pages that I have created on my website, but receive the same not found error when I click on any links. I just want to be able to login to my Wordpress admin.

Comment: Are you running XAMPP or MAMP?

Comment: I am running MAMP